# Extending (alternative to) the repository desing pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository, repository-pattern

I am working on a project in ASP.NET MVC. I want to create an abstraction layer between the data access layer and the business logic layer of an application. I have been working with Repository and Unit of work. To review, in this pattern a general repository and a number of specific repositories is being created. The problem I have faced in this project is that I need method of some specific repository in another repository. For example, I have a Product and Subproduct repository. I want to use Subproduct methods inside Product methods instead of rewriting LINQ Queries for Subproduct every time. Is there any way to extend the functionaltiy of repository design pattern, or I have to use another design pattern?

```
public class ProductSubcategoryRepository : Repository<ProductSubcategory>, IProductSubcategoryRepository
{
    public ProductSubcategoryRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductSubcategory> CheckSomeCondition()
    {
        // LINQ to check some condition based on product subcategory
    }
}

public class ProductCategoryRepository : Repository<ProductCategory>, IProductCategoryRepository
{
    public ProductCategoryRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> GetProductCategoriesBeforeDate()
    {
        // Repeated LINQ to check some condition based on product subcategory 
        // (I am looking for a way to call the same method of ProductSubCategory calss)

        // LINQ To return List of product category if the previous query is true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already said in your question that you have Business Logic Layer in place. That is the best place to manage this stuff.

So, you do not call one repository in other. Instead, you call two repositories in one method from BLL to achieve the target. Hopefully, your UoW is exposed to BLL. That way, under same scope of UoW, you execute both the actions.

This is not only limited to `Get`ting the records. This can be further extended to `Get`-`Modify`-`Update` or whatever.

I am not sure what your `CheckSomeCondition` does. It it is just a Predicate then that is fine. If it is part of some business logic, better way is to shift it to BLL as I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to make `ProductCategoryRepository` creates an instance of `ProductSubcategoryRepository` inside its constructor:

```
public class ProductCategoryRepository : Repository<ProductCategory>, IProductCategoryRepository
{
    private ProductSubcategoryRepository subRepo;
    public ProductCategoryRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        subRepo = new ProductSubcategoryRepository(context);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> GetProductCategoriesBeforeDate()
    {
        // call subRepo
    }
}
```

If you already have an instance of `ProductSubcategoryRepository` you can inject it:

```
public ProductCategoryRepository(DbContext context, ProductSubcategoryRepository subRepo) : base(context)
{
    this.subRepo = subRepo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for consideration. However I am looking for a general method. In the example, I have one class but what if I have a lot of classes.

Comment: hmm, but after all you have to explicitly specify which classes need to reuse code from which classes, so I don't think there is a general solution here. But would love to see such a solution too.